# Starvation of Winforms control invalidation

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, directx

I have two instances of a graphics WinForms control. The graphics is rendered by DirectX and may contain animated content.

I started implementing the continuously-rendered content by:

```
public override void OnPaint(...)
{
    base.OnPaint(...);

    // Render scene

    this.Invalidate();
}
```

Besides high CPU usage, this method causes for starvation of invalidation of other controls: One of the controls is rerendered again and again and other controls waiting for the CPU to perform their invalidation request, which is never happen (unless forcing it in some way like window resize).

So I removed 'this.Invalidate()' call and call it only when a refresh is needed. It does solve the problem when no animation is displayed, but if both controls show animated content the problem appears again.

I thought about managing all controls in the application in a centralized manager which will 'schedule' Invalidate calls in round robin. However I'm not happy with the need to know all controls in the application in one centralized location, and I'm not sure if this is the right way to overcome the problem.

Is there a standard way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't `Invalidate` during a paint event.  That is just going to cause *another* paint event, again and again and again forever.  You want to `Invalidate` when your data changes, and you can also `Invalidate` only a region if possible to minimize redraw.

For an animation you will want to call `Invalidate` based upon your frame rate. You can use a `Timer` or some other mechanism to do so.

Comment: Thanks for reply, it's good to know my implementation is not standard. However when an animation is used, invalidation again and again immediately after rendering each frame results in much smoother animation (and I have some clients who notice the difference...). Because animation is for short times I'm OK with rendering such ways and consume CPU, but I still don't want that an animated controls will cause other controls to starve. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @MaMazav: Like I said, use a timer.  Let's say you want to refresh at 20fps.  So, create a timer, set the interval to 1000 / 20 = 50ms and, in the Tick event, call `Invalidate`.